# How to set default android black color for a child layout while its parent having another background color?

Tags: android, android-layout, background-color

I have a child layout inside its parent layout. If i set any background color for parent, it sets the same color for its child also. But i don't want to set the same color for child. (I want the default android black color as background for child). Please help me. 

EDITED: 

 I need to capture the child layout and create a bitmap later, So i should not set any  background color for child (but its parent should has some color). It should set to default android black only.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#FFA500" >

    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Parent linear layout has some BG color. I didn't set any BG color for child relative layout but it is taking parent's BG color. So now, how can i set android default BG color for child ?

Comment: The child is a View. So get it by using yourParentView.findViewByid(R.id.yourChildId); and set it's background color

Comment: I have edited my question. I don't want any background for child layout while its parent having some color.

Comment: I dont understand what you want to do

Answer (score 0):

You can set the background color of the child layout to transparent.

Set:

`android:background="00000000";`

First 2 hex numbers are the alpha component for your background.

Comment: if i set android:background="#00000000" for child, it is showing the same BG color for Child also. (But when i capture child layout, it is not taking any BG color)

Comment: Isn't there any way to stop child inherting BG color from its parent ?

Comment: you can always change the background color of the layaout programatically after capturing the child layout!

Comment: If i capture the child layout (with some BG color) and create a bitmap, Is it possible to remove the BG color of bitmap ?

Answer (score 0):

> If i set any background color for parent, it sets the same color for
>   its child also

No it doesn't. Your child just has a transparent background by default, so it looks like it's inheriting the color from its parent. Just set it to something else other than transparent.

Edit:

Sorry, just read your edit.

If you want to add an image to your child view later, instead of setting `setBackgroundDrawable` or something, use `setImageBitmap`. It will retain the transparent color of your child view, while displaying the image you specified.